# Is it possible to change a part of text styling of ChoiceGroupOption (office-ui-fabric)?

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric, office-ui-fabric-react

I am using Office fabric `Choice Group` for my radio buttons. I would like to change the styling of part of text to `bold`, but the rest of text remains as normal font size. I am using `onRenderField` method but I have not successfully implemented yet.... I really appreciate any inputs!!

**Final Goal for radio button text:**

> **On:** some additional explanation here

**Example Code using `onRenderField` method:**

```
options={[
  {
    key: 'On', 
    text: 'On: some additional explanation here', 
    onRenderField: (props, render) => {
      return (
        <span style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>
          {render!(props)}
        </span>
      );
    }
  }
]}
```

**The above code makes `bold` entire `text` like below:**

> **On: some additional explanation here**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an option that doesn't appear to be well-documented called `onRenderLabel` that will do what you need.

Using it looks like:

```
{
  key: 'C',
  text: 'Option C',
  onRenderLabel: (p) => <span id={p.labelId} className="ms-ChoiceFieldLabel">Option C: only <strong>this part</strong> is bold</span>
}
```

The `p` in the callback is of type `IChoiceGroupOptionProps` and may be of use, though it's more likely that defining the entire render inline is easier. ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-ui-fabric-react/ichoicegroupoptionprops?view=office-ui-fabric-react-latest )

Comment: Working example (along with some other override styles shown) at https://codepen.io/jdh-msft/pen/bGEGeRV?editors=0010

Comment: Hi JD! Thank you for the suggestion! I could achieve what I wanted using onRenderLabel! Could you let me know how you could identify the right className for the label..? I thought I needed to create a custom styling for label but `className="ms-ChoiceFieldLabel"' worked perfectly.

Comment: I found this by looking at the source directly. Unfortunately I don't know of a better way! In this case, the classname is baked right into the component:
https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/blob/a6523e210c0a534e81a2ead3a6135d51dbc263b6/packages/office-ui-fabric-react/src/components/ChoiceGroup/ChoiceGroupOption/ChoiceGroupOption.base.tsx#L146

Comment: Thank you! That is really helpful :)